# How to add instagram-like filters to video files with ruby?

Tags: ruby, video-processing

See the title, is there a ruby gem or service that I can use to add filter effects to video files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will find a reliable and up-to-date gem or service.

Probably your best bet in Ruby is to automate use of `ffmpeg` command line utility directly. With this you could render a video to separate audio track and individual frames as images (e.g. jpegs). Then use a gem like `rmagick` to apply an effect to each frame image in turn, and finally use `ffmpeg` again to stitch it all back together. This is probably lower-level work than you were hoping, but as far as I know is all that's easily and freely available.

The following Ruby code applies a charcoal drawing effect to a video:

```
require 'rmagick'

INPUT_VIDEO = 'Test.mp4'
OUTPUT_VIDEO = 'Charcoal.mp4'

# Extract audio
`ffmpeg -y -i #{INPUT_VIDEO} -ab 64k -ac 2 Audio.aac`

# Extract frames
`ffmpeg -y -i #{INPUT_VIDEO} Frame%04d.png`

# Convert frames
Dir.glob('Frame*.png').each do |frame|
  frame_img = Magick::Image.read( frame )
  new_frame = frame_img[0].gaussian_blur
  new_frame = new_frame.charcoal
  new_frame = new_frame.negate
  new_frame.write( "Converted" + frame )
end

# Stitch back together
`ffmpeg -y -r 25 -i ConvertedFrame%04d.png -i Audio.aac -r 25 #{OUTPUT_VIDEO}`
```

Please note a lot of important `ffmpeg` parameters have been omitted in the above example. Chances of the audio being in sync in the example are low. Check FFmpeg documentation!

Comment: This is pretty slow, but for quick experimenting this is a great solution, in conjunction with ImageMagick-based filters like those in https://github.com/acoomans/instagram-filters. Any idea how I would go about improving performance when I'll get the look I want? Cheers!

Comment: @julien_c: There are some filters built into `ffmpeg`, via the `-vf` option which you could take a look at: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters . Other than that maybe ruby-opencv is a better bet

Answer (score 1):

A very popular library for video manipulation is [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Here are the [docs for supported video filters](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters). You will have to mix them to get the effect you are looking for.

You can use this by wrapping the command line parameters, but one of these tools may work (I have not tested them).

- [RVideo](http://rvideo.rubyforge.org/)
- [FFmpeg](https://github.com/tja/ruby-ffmpeg)

Comment: `rvideo` does not seem very up-to-date, I think the OP is better off wrapping system calls to `ffmpeg` directly.

Comment: That's why I said the tools *may* work. They were just the two best options I found online. I too would wrap the system calls. Then again, I would probably create a new gem if I needed to do this.